# How to vibrate/ring on click of link

Tags: browser, audio, settings, vibration, haptic-feedback

How can I make my samsung galaxy tab vibrate or ring when I click a link on a browser? thanks a lot for any help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature does not exist, the only thing I could suggest is to submit a feature request on the [Android Issues Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list).